# Extracting surface points in module lasground of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I need an advice. I have Lastools installed in QGIS 2.18.16 (Las Palmas). But the problem is that I cannot extract LIDAR from the initially classified data, according to the instructions on the official site https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html The manual is like a different lasground module. Lastools, specifically the lasground module is completely different for input and output data. Check image.

[image]

Can you tell me how to enter the data in the lasground module to extract ground data?